# This just doesn't seem to be a good question to me

Tags: discussion

[Are there any instances of disaster movies coming true?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/are-there-any-instances-of-disaster-movies-coming-true/1610#1610)

I don't particularly care for this question, it's a list question.

Comment: Surprisingly it has 10 up votes. You proposing to close?

Comment: If close, mark as historical to salvage?

Comment: It was finally flagged by someone, so I decided to close it. Overall opinion seems to be that it's not a great question and clearly inviting a list of answers as currently written.

Comment: I'm glad to see that the question was _quickly_ re-openned. Maybe the re-wording had something to do with that, but I think probably not; this turned out to be much ado about nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at it now, I agree. There is no one right answer. I didn't initially see it as a list question because I thought there really was only one answer. But the language is in the question itself: "Are there any instances..." is asking people to list movies. Plus, there is only one way to answer something like this for it to be a satisfactory answer, and that is by *listing* the movies that came out before real-world disasters occurred that mirrored what happened in those movies.

I still think the topic is interesting, but I don't see anything exceptionally great happening with it right now. I vote to close until I can come up with a better way to ask the question.

Suggestions/thoughts/feelings/emotions/declarations of war all welcome!

EDIT:
Updated. If the edit is acceptable and adequately addresses the concerns made here, please vote to reopen so we all can work toward taking this question from less-than-useful to a useful addition to the site.

Comment: Easiest thing I can think of is making it a "What is the first instance of a disaster movie coming true?"

Comment: That certainly does narrow the scope, and per the discussion on the Meta regarding "What is the first..." questions, it should be okay. Much more challenging answer to find, as well.

Comment: At this point I'm not certain how to proceed. I know what changes I want but there are already answers that don't necessarily answer the 'new' question (What is the first instance of a disaster movie coming true?). Is that acceptable? Or should an entirely new question be asked?

Comment: It should be fine to edit your question as such, and then leave a comment on the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting at best, a list question at worst.  Do with it what you will.